# Why is this approach incorrect? - Circular motion

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

Would like to start by saying I know how to solve this problem - now I just want to know why one of my original methods was wrong.

> Fixed points A, B and C are in a vertical line with A above B and B above C. A particle Q of mass 3kg is joined to A, to B and to a particle P of mass 2kg, by three light rods where the length of rod AQ is 2m and the length of rod QP is 1m. Particle Q moves in a horizontal circle with centre B. Particle P moves in a horizontal circle with centre C at the same constant angular speed $\omega$ as Q, so hat A, B, P and Q are coplanar. Rods AQ and QP both make an angle of $30^{\circ}$ with the downward vertical, and rod BQ is horizontal.
>
> Calculate the angular speed $\omega$.

See diagram:[image: Diagram]

My original method:

Find the tension in the rod AQ:

$$T\:=\:\frac{5g}{cos\left(30\right)}$$

We also know that

$$T\:sin\left(30\right)\:=\:5\:\cdot 2\sin \left(30\right)\cdot \omega ^2$$

$$\omega =\sqrt{\frac{5g\cdot sin\left(30\right)}{sin\left(60\right)\cdot 5\cdot 2\sin \left(30\right)}}=2.38\:rad\:s^{-1}$$

This is the wrong answer. But I get the right answer when I change the radius from 2sin(30) to 3sin(30) - which doesn't make sense as then I'm looking beyond rod AQ?

Comment: Why do you assume there is no tension in rod $PQ$? You should balance $Q$'s weight by upward components of both the tension forces (in $AQ$ and $PQ$)

Comment: Also, the centripetal force in rotating Q should be equated to the net horizontal component of tensions in all 3 rods in the inward direction

Comment: The 3 kg mass at point $Q$ is a red herring.  That value is not relevant to the solution of the problem.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi yes, you can just calculate angular speed by tension in $PQ$, which you know from weight of $P$

Comment: @ab123 Even the mass at point $P$ has no impact on the solution, because the $m$ in the centripetal force and the one in the force of gravity cancel out.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi yeah, even simpler!

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess I'm not familiar enough with the concept of tension and centripetal force yet to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Rod PQ is free to rotate about Q. If it settles at an angle of 30 degrees, it is because the torques of the forces acting on the mass at P balance out for that angle. Choose the axis through Q for the computation of the moments to keep things simple: specifically, to keep the tension in $PQ$ out of the equation. Tensions can be computed later, but bringing them into the computation early is not a great idea.

Comment: Cool! Just a few questions however. What's a torque? I understand that its a force that causes rotation, but what would it be in this case? The gravity and the centripetal force? I'm not really sure. 2) This is a bit of a stupid question, but how does choosing the axis through Q allow me to ignore the tension in PQ? I'm not a physicist (or planning to be one haha) so this is really confusing. Thanks!

Comment: You need the tension along PQ to compute the speed.

Comment: @RafaBudría You don't need the tension. You can derive the angular speed from the rotational equilibrium equation $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} m r \omega^2 = \frac{1}{2} mg$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi We can isolate $\omega$ without knowing the tension, but the tension is the force that meakes the mass at P rotate, this is my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation is not right. The wording says that Q is attached to B by a rod, so, your analysis for the particle at Q must include the force the rod from B to Q exerts outward over the particle in Q. To know the intensity of this force we need to know the acceleration (two equations for Q and three unknowns), so is, the angular speed.

We are forced to analyze the particle at P as we have only two bodies interacting with it, the Earth (gravity force) and the rod from Q to P. Your equations are ok if you put 2 kg for the mass and $3\sin30º$ for the radius.

$T=\dfrac{2 kg}{\cos30º}$

$T\cdot \sin30º=2 kg\cdot 3 m\cdot \sin30º\cdot \omega ^2$